# Plot data in groups

Tags: r, dataframe, plot, ggplot2, data.table

I want to plot data that can be sorted into 2 groups (Tornado and TSTM WIND). My data is like that:

[image]

Now I want to create a simple chart with the sum of FATALITIES for each EVTYPE. So there would be one value for Tornado ( 30 in this case) and one value for TSTM WIND( 20)

I tried this but it won`t work because I seemingly have arguments with different sizes

```
 xcv<-aggregate(E0, by = list(Fatalities), FUN = sum, na.rm = TRUE)
 plot(Fatalities)
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this pretty easily using the data.table or dplyr packages. Simple examples below.

If you want to make the plot nicer I would recommend having a look at ggplot.

```
# create example data frame: 

df <- data.frame(EVTYPE = c("Tornado","TSTM Wind","Tornado","TSTM Wind"), Fatalities = c(1,3,4,6))

# use data.table
library(data.table)

df <- data.table(df)
df[,sum(Fatalities), keyby = EVTYPE]

plot(df[,sum(Fatalities), keyby = EVTYPE])

# with dplyr

df %>% group_by(EVTYPE) %>% summarise(sum = sum(Fatalities)) %>% plot()
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to sum at the same time as plotting by using **ggplot**:

```
require(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = EVTYPE, y = FATALITIES, fill = EVTYPE)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  xlab("Event Type") +
  ylab("Fatalities") +
  guides(fill=FALSE)
```

Output:

[image]

Sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  EVTYPE=c("Tornado","TSTM Wind","TSTM Wind","Tornado","TSTM Wind",
           "Tornado","TSTM Wind","TSTM Wind","Tornado","Tornado"),
  FATALITIES=c(5,11,2,1,1,2,3,3,1,21)
)
```